# Converting Long to Varchar2

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00997

I am trying to insert into varchar2 column from a long column. here is the below example, `TEXT.TEXT_COL = VARCHAR2(4000)`
and `NOTE.TEXT_NOTE = LONG`.

```
INSERT INTO TEXT(ROW_ID, TEXT_COL)
SELECT 1, TEXT_NOTE FROM NOTE;
```

When i run the above sql i get error

> SQL Error: ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

I used `TO_LOB()` too, but still the same error.

Is there any function which simply coverts `long` and put it in `varchar2`. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: you cannot do it in a single statement using only built-in procedures, see [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2429393)

Comment: You'd need to use PL/SQL or an intermediate table with a CLOB column. You may want a CLOB anyway if any of the values in the LONG column are more than 4000 bytes, of course; or are you happy truncating those?

Comment: I have to use this sql in informatica session level. I tried at the mapping level of informatica built in datatypes but its not working either.

Comment: is there any other way i can handle this ?

Comment: Did CAST(TEXT_NOTE AS VARCHAR)  throw an error at you?

Answer (score 18):

Converting from `long` to `varchar2` right away using a single statement is not possible, as `long` has certain restrictions.

You can either **Create a temporary table** or use **PL/SQL code** to solve your problem:

- Temporary Table:

  `CREATE TABLE TABLE2 AS SELECT TO_LOB(COLUMN1) COLUMN FROM TABLE1;`
- PL/SQL Code:

  ```
  DECLARE
    VAR1 LONG;
    VAR2 VARCHAR2(4000);
  BEGIN
    SELECT TEXT INTO VAR1 FROM USER_VIEWS WHERE ROWNUM = 1;  
    VAR2 := SUBSTR(VAR1, 1, 4000);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VAR2);
  END;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Oracle internally converts LONG to something else (probably CLOB) when you select LONG in FOR loop. I did not find any explanations in Oracle documentation, but this works

```
BEGIN
  FOR V IN (SELECT ROWID,TEXT_NOTE FROM NOTE)
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO TEXT VALUES(V.ROWID, SUBSTR(V.TEXT_NOTE, 1, 4000) );   
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

This is an example how to copy all views from another schema to your schema

```
BEGIN
  FOR V IN (SELECT VIEW_NAME, TEXT_LENGTH, TEXT FROM ALL_VIEWS WHERE OWNER = 'PROD')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW '||V.VIEW_NAME||' AS '||SUBSTR(V.TEXT, 1, V.TEXT_LENGTH);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('View '||V.VIEW_NAME||' created');
  END LOOP;
END;
```

For some reason it only works for FOR loop and does not work if you use WITH or select from another query

```
INSERT INTO TEXT
WITH V AS(SELECT ROWID ROW_ID,TEXT_NOTE FROM NOTE)
SELECT V.ROW_ID, SUBSTR(V.TEXT_NOTE, 1, 4000) FROM V; 

INSERT INTO TEXT
SELECT ROW_ID, SUBSTR(TEXT_NOTE, 1, 4000) 
FROM (SELECT ROWID ROW_ID,TEXT_NOTE FROM NOTE);
```

Both inserts raise the same error

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG

Comment: When TEXT_LENGTH is greater than 32760 the select ... from ALL_VIEWS will throw the error "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: Bulk Bind: Truncated Bind" (I tested on "Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit" with different views to get that limit number (I don't know why not the same as max of varchar2 (32767)).

Answer (score 0):

you can use standard function to convert long to varchar2:

```
sys.DBMS_METADATA_UTIL.long2varchar
```

or to clob:

```
sys.DBMS_METADATA_UTIL.long2clob
```