# Cast long to varchar Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, casting

Is there a way to cast long datatype to varchar on Oracle?

table 1:
[image]

table 2:
[image]

Errors:

[image: Try1]
[image: Try2]

Example of data on table 1 (table 2 is the same but without 'GUID|' and it's a varchar):

[image]

Obs.:

- I can not create another table (create as select);
- I've tried use pl/sql to select long into varchar (didn't work);
- to_char doesn't work;
- I have to update lines on table 1 that are in table 2;

Comment: LONG's are evil. Can you change the data type to something which is supported (BLOB/CLOB)?

Comment: The only way I know how is similar to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31007149/6233138). Use a temp table or PL/SQL.

Comment: [Here's another link](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=430) that goes into detail on different ways to convert LONG to VARCHAR2. Good luck.