# How to cast LONG to VARCHAR2 inline

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Background: [`ALL_IND_EXPRESSIONS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1065.htm) has column

> ```
> COLUMN_EXPRESSION   LONG   Function-based index expression defining the column
> ```

I know that [`LONG`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i3056) is deprecated. I need to write something like (or do other text operations):

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    q'{ALTER INDEX "<index_owner>"."<index_name>" ON ... (<column_expression>)}'
   ,'<index_owner>', index_owner )
   ,'<index_name>', index_name) 
   ,'<column_expression>', column_expression) AS result
FROM all_ind_expressions;
```

> ORA-00932: **inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got LONG**

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e1a7c592349d7305ca78568aaaa06697)**

Remarks:

- it has to be self-contained query
- no intermediate objects(creating table/view is not an option).
- no `PL/SQL block`
- `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` (it is not the case)
- [WITH FUNCTION clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1#functions) as last resort

Is it possible to cast/convert/use built-in function from `LONG` to `VARCHAR2`?

**EDIT TL;DR:**

```
SELECT column_expression || 'a'  -- convert to working code
FROM all_ind_expressions;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Long to Varchar2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31004844/converting-long-to-varchar2)

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO Mentioned answer could be helpful. `Converting from long to varchar2 right away using a single statement is not possible, as long has certain restrictions.` any link to official documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use XML unless expressions contain something which can brake XML parsing.

```
select *
  from xmltable(
          '/ROWSET/ROW'
          passing (select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select * from all_ind_expressions
                                                   where index_name = ''XDB$COMPLEX_TYPE_AK''')
                     from dual)
          columns index_owner varchar2(30) path 'INDEX_OWNER',
                  index_name varchar2(30) path 'INDEX_NAME',
                  table_owner varchar2(30) path 'TABLE_OWNER',
                  table_name varchar2(30) path 'TABLE_NAME',
                  column_expression varchar2(4000) path 'COLUMN_EXPRESSION')

INDEX_OWNER     INDEX_NAME           TABLE_OWNER     TABLE_NAME           COLUMN_EXPRESSION                  
--------------- -------------------- --------------- -------------------- -----------------------------------
XDB             XDB$COMPLEX_TYPE_AK  XDB             XDB$COMPLEX_TYPE     SYS_OP_R2O("XMLDATA"."ALL_KID")    
1 row selected.
```

Comment: Thanks for idea, I will test it :) I hope it will work for all my cases (I don't want to create exceptions for non-parsable XML)

Comment: I modified this select to extract column HIGH_VALUE from ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS.

Answer (score 4):

Using `WITH FUNCTION` and approach from [Converting Long to Varchar2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31004844/converting-long-to-varchar2) but still it is somehow ugly and overcomplicated.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(Z INT);
CREATE INDEX IF_DOUBLE_TEST_Z ON TEST(Z*2);
```

Query:

```
WITH FUNCTION s_convert(pindex_owner VARCHAR2, pindex_name VARCHAR2,
                        ptable_owner VARCHAR2, ptable_name VARCHAR2) 
               RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  VAR1 LONG;
  VAR2 VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT column_expression 
  INTO VAR1 
  FROM all_ind_expressions
  WHERE index_owner = pindex_owner AND index_name = pindex_name
    AND table_owner = ptable_owner AND table_name = ptable_name
    AND column_position = 1;  -- only one column indexes

  VAR2 := SUBSTR(VAR1, 1, 4000);
  RETURN VAR2;
END;
SELECT aie.*, 
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
     q'{ALTER INDEX "<index_owner>"."<index_name>" ON ... (<column_expression>)}'
     ,'<index_owner>', index_owner )
     ,'<index_name>', index_name) 
     ,'<column_expression>', 
       s_convert(index_owner, index_name, table_owner, table_name)) AS result
FROM all_ind_expressions aie
WHERE TABLE_NAME='TEST';
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=28346ea1d5aa7db1c2a5126a5f11ec0c)**

I believe that there should be more elegant way to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by oracle experts themselves, for legacy reasons it's not possible to inline SUBSTR a LONG to a VARCHAR2. [AskTom link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f%3Fp%3D100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:412605596308).

On this [other link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:665224430110) you'll find ways to do it with a procedure and even with a function if the LONG is shorter that 32k LONG.

And this function can be called later on in a SELECT query, which is what you may want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with long is to: 
1) Create a temporary table with a lob type (eg. CLOB).
2) Use the only allowed syntax by oracle:
"TO_LOB converts LONG or LONG RAW values in the column long_column to LOB values. You can apply this function only to a LONG or LONG RAW column, and only in the select list of a subquery in an INSERT statement."
3) exploit the temporary table to do your stuff